# Stop workflows from running on Forked repositories

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I do have a public repository to which people may contribute, by creating PRs from their forks.

My workflows should only run on the main repository and not be triggered for forked ones.

Is there a way to disable workflows completely on triggering configuration?

I know I can skip it early by checking `GITHUB_REPOSITORY` - but it will still run - which I don't want to have.

I do have these as triggers:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - "extensions/**"
    branches: [main, master]
  push:
    paths:
      - "extensions/**"
    branches: [main, master]
```

Comment: Are you using the `pull_request_target` event in your public repository? I remember [this part of the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks) talking about manually approving runs when not using this trigger.

Comment: I updated my question - I am using `pull_request` and `push`